# FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to test what happens when VAE's posterior is GMM. I wrote the code, but there is an error:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import functools
import os

# Dependency imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from absl import flags
import numpy as np
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.datasets import mnist

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
tfd = tfp.distributions

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
test_images = test_images.reshape(test_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')

# BACK TO [0,1]
train_images /= 255.
test_images /= 255.

# Binarized
train_images[train_images >= .5] = 1.  # shape = (60000,28,28,1)
train_images[train_images < .5] = 0.

base_depth = 32
latent_size = 2
mixture_components = 10
IMAGE_SHAPE = [28, 28, 1]

# encoder

x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
h1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=base_depth, kernel_size=5, strides=1,
                            padding='same', activation='relu')

h2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=base_depth, kernel_size=5, strides=2,
                            padding='same', activation='relu')

h3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=base_depth * 2, kernel_size=5, strides=1,
                            padding='same', activation='relu')

h4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=base_depth * 2, kernel_size=5, strides=2,
                            padding='same', activation='relu')

h5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=base_depth * 6, kernel_size=3, strides=1,
                            padding='same', activation='relu')

h6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=latent_size * 4, kernel_size=7, padding='valid'
                            , activation='relu')

flatten1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

encoder_end = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2 * mixture_components * latent_size + mixture_components, activation=None)

e1 = h1(x)
e2 = h2(e1)
e3 = h3(e2)
e4 = h4(e3)
e5 = h5(e4)
e6 = h6(e5)
e7 = flatten1(e6)
encoder_out = encoder_end(e7)  # parameters of GMM
# split {mean,variance,pi}
loc, raw_scale_diag, mixture_logits = tf.split(encoder_out,
                                               [latent_size * mixture_components, latent_size * mixture_components,
                                                mixture_components], axis=-1)

loc = tf.reshape(loc, [-1, mixture_components, latent_size])

raw_scale_diag = tf.reshape(raw_scale_diag, [-1, mixture_components, latent_size])  # [B,k,E]

# posterior
approx_posterior = tfd.MixtureSameFamily(components_distribution=tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(
    loc=loc,
    scale_diag=tf.nn.softplus(raw_scale_diag)),
    mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(logits=mixture_logits),
)
# sample from posterior (16 latent variable z)
approx_posterior_samples = approx_posterior._sample_n(16, seed=None)

# decoder
decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(2 * base_depth, kernel_size=7, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(2 * base_depth, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(2 * base_depth, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(base_depth, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(base_depth, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(base_depth, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(IMAGE_SHAPE[-1], kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation=None)
])

original_shape = tf.shape(input=approx_posterior_samples)
approx_posterior_samples = tf.reshape(approx_posterior_samples, (-1, 1, 1, latent_size))

logits = decoder(approx_posterior_samples)
logits = tf.reshape(
    logits, shape=tf.concat([original_shape[:-1], IMAGE_SHAPE], axis=0))
logits = tf.reduce_mean(logits, axis=0)
logits = tf.reshape(logits, shape=tf.shape(x))
# bulid model
model = tf.keras.Model(x, logits)



# prior of z (also GMM)
def make_mixture_prior(latent_size, mixture_components):

    loc = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(
        name="loc", shape=[mixture_components, latent_size])
    raw_scale_diag = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(
        name="raw_scale_diag", shape=[mixture_components, latent_size])
    mixture_logits = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(
        name="mixture_logits", shape=[mixture_components])

    return tfd.MixtureSameFamily(
        components_distribution=tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(
            loc=loc,
            scale_diag=tf.nn.softplus(raw_scale_diag)),
        mixture_distribution=tfd.Categorical(logits=mixture_logits),
        name="prior")


# latent_size=2,mixture_components=10
latent_prior = make_mixture_prior(2, 10)
# reconstruction error
distortion = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=x, logits=logits)
avg_distortion = tf.reduce_mean(distortion)
# kl divergence
rate = (approx_posterior.log_prob(approx_posterior_samples) - latent_prior.log_prob(approx_posterior_samples))
avg_rate = tf.reduce_mean(rate)

loss = avg_distortion + avg_rate
# custom loss
model.add_loss(loss)
```

Here is the error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable mixture_logits from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/mixture_logits/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node prior_1/log_prob/Categorical_2/logits_parameter/Identity/ReadVariableOp}}]]
     [[prior_1/log_prob/LogSoftmax/_269]]
  (1) Failed precondition: Error while reading resource variable mixture_logits from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Resource localhost/mixture_logits/class tensorflow::Var does not exist.
     [[{{node prior_1/log_prob/Categorical_2/logits_parameter/Identity/ReadVariableOp}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

### I Have two questions as follows:

1.Is the way I model this type of vae correct(use Model(input,output))?

2. Whether the way i define my loss is correct?

I think my errors may came from above questions.

### Finally,i have tried before in several ways:

1.

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),
tf.local_variables_initializer()])
```

2.
consider the "tensorflow.compat.v1.keras  and  tensorflow.keras " error

they really doesn't work for me!